# How to get elapsed time with system.time?

Tags: r

Is there a way to get just the numerical value of elapsed time from system.time?

I want to measure the elapsed time of a bunch of functions I wrote. I call those functions like this:

```
time_f1 <- system.time({
  function_1(x,y,z)
  and some other stuff
})
time_f2 <- system.time({
  function_2(x,y,z)
  and some other stuff
})
...
```

`time_f1` and the other measured times are objects of type `proc_time` and I have to extract the elapsed time.

Is there a possibility to directly get only the numerical value of the elapsed times, so i can store them in a vector like this:

```
time_f[1] <- system.time::elapsed({
  function_1(x,y,z)
  and some other stuff
})
time_f[2] <- system.time::elapsed({
  function_2(x,y,z)
  and some other stuff
})
```

I know that `system.time::elapsed` doesn't exist but is there something comperable? I couldn't find anything in the `help()` for `system.time` or `proc.time`.

Comment: I strongly suggest the `microbenchmark`  package for such measurements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
system.time(log(1:1e5))["elapsed"]
#elapsed 
#  0.002
```

To only get the numerical value do

```
system.time(log(1:1e5))[["elapsed"]]
```